# How I can pass a Dimension in dp with databinding with an included layout?

Tags: android, include, android-databinding

I'm trying to pass a paddingTop for an included layout but I can't find the way. I try to pass a dimen defined in a resources file, an int, putting the variable type to int and passing dp, the only way I found it works is defining the variable as an int and passing an int.

This is the included layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="image"
        type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable" />

    <variable
        name="notification"
        type="int" />
    <variable
        name="paddingTop"
        type="androidx.annotation.Dimension" />

</data>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="@{paddingTop}"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="7dp"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_tab_home_selector"
            android:src="@{image}"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_notification_circle"
            android:fontFamily="@font/muli"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(notification)}"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:visibility="@{notification > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is how I'm trying to pass the dimension:

```
 <include
            android:id="@+id/tab_home"
            layout="@layout/layout_tab_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:notification="@{1}"
            app:paddingTop="@{4dp}"
            app:image="@{@drawable/ic_tab_home_selector}"/>
```

Comment: is there a reason you aren't using the dimen from the dimen file directly? eg. paddingTop = "@dimen/general_padding"

Comment: No, but if I pass a dimen in the paddingTop for example app:paddingTop="@{@dimen/general_padding}" , it not works too. I explain that in the comments of the question.

Comment: No, all you need is paddingTop = "@dimen/general_padding" and then define general_padding in your dimen xml file. You have to many other @ and {} symbols. Your viewModel has nothing to do with setting dimensions.

Comment: No doing that the code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variable as Float

```
<variable
    name="paddingTop"
    type="Float" />
```

and then you can pass a dimen to the layout

```
<YourLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:paddingTop="@{@dimen/yourDimen}"/>
```